# deploy openfire xmpp in aws elastic beanstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, openfire

I have installed openfire on my windows system. It is working fine. Now I want to deploy openfire xmpp server on AWS elastic beanstack . I have been searching on web with no solutions.
How to deploy openfire xmpp in aws elastic beanstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom AMI and install openfire there, then create your Beanstalk with this AMI.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it your existing beanstalk environment.

1. need to login to ur aws environment/instance using putty.

   In order to login you need to have .pem file converted to.ppk
2. using wget download the openfire from its site (tar.gz file)
3. extract tarfile from downlaoded tar into /usr/local/
   EX:  extract it using tar -zxvf openfire.tar.gz
4. cd /openfire/bin/ (Go into bin folder)
5. sh openfire start. (Start the openfire)

   This will start the server

   Check its status using sh openfire status from bin folder.